# Pm2 script not found when executing config file app.json/process.yml

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2

I have tried using `app.json` and `process.yml` for my very simple NodeJS application. The application are group of scripts which would run as a background job in server and hence I want to do it using `pm2 configuration file` which looks like -

```
{
 "apps":[
  {
    "name":"dodge-report",
    "script":"dodge-report/dodge-report.js local"
  },
  {
    "name":"dodge-filter",
    "script":"dodge-filter/dodge-filter.js local"
  }
 ]
}
```

when I am trying to execute it using `pm2 start app.json` it one of the app works fine while other throws an error -

[image]

Both the path for scripts are 100% correct and scripts are in place, so wrong path or missing script file is out of question. I am not sure what is wrong any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure `/dodge-filter/dodge-filter.js` path is correct. Since it begins with a slash, it will look for `dodge-filter` folder in root directory.

Comment: Yes both the path are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If dodge-filter/dodge-filter.js path is relative to pm2 conf execution,
kindly use the paths like this : `./dodge-filter/dodge-filter.js`

If you prefer giving the full system path, that should make this work too!

```
/var/www/html/dodge-filter/dodge-filter.js
```